# Selenium webdriver giving connection timeout error

Tags: selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, python-requests, webdriver

Due to confidentionality i can't share the whole idea but i will try to give you whole picture that you can understand and help me.
Some links are types that we render it broswer it automatically download ,most of the time extension of those url are .docs
for example this [link](https://onjn.gov.ro/wp-content/uploads/Onjn.gov.ro/Legislatie/OUG%2077%202009%20la%20zi%202022.docx).
When i render this link using slenium webdriver on local machine like linux ubuntu it work fine in headless and headfull mode it downloading automatically fine. But the probelm become when i run same script on linux server machine it giving me connection time out error.
Can you help me? if you need more information i would love to share .

i tried on local machine using selenium webdriver  it working fine but the probelm raise when i run same script on linux server machine then it giving me connection time out error

Comment: have you installed the latest chromedriver and check if the browser is up to date?

Comment: yes , they are updated .

Comment: The version of browser and chrome driver are Version 119.0.6045.123